# Getting "stack overflow" error while serializing/deserializing specific files

Tags: c#, xml

I was trying to just serialize/deserialize data from my specific files, but it just gives me stack overflow exception. It also writes this at the console

```
at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at csproj.coupMechanics..ctor()
   at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at csproj.coupMechanics..ctor()
   at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at csproj.coupMechanics..ctor()
   at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at csproj.coupMechanics..ctor()
   at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at csproj.coupMechanics..ctor()
   at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at csproj.coupMechanics..ctor()
   at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at csproj.coupMechanics..ctor()
   at csproj.gameManagement..ctor()
   at Program.<Main>$(System.String[])
```

Here is coup mechanics class

```
public class coupMechanics : coupSettings
    public string path = @$"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\nothing\msd-temp-file.xml";
    public string path2 = $@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\nothing\deletable.txt";

    gameManagement gm = new gameManagement();
    user u = new user();
    player temprorary = null;

    public List<player> players = new List<player>();
    public XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<player>));
}
```

and here's game managment class

```
try
{
    using (fs = new FileStream(c.path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        users = (List<user>)c.xs.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    foreach (var idi in users)
    {
        if (idi.id.CompareTo(id) == 1)
        {
            id = idi.id;
        }
    }
    id++;
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    id = 0;
}
```

Of course, theese are just the small parts of my code.

Everything looks fine, except it doesnt work. So what do I do?

Comment: `coupMechanics` clearly instantiates a new `gameManagement` (`gm`); presumably `gameManagement` is doing the same thing in the opposite direction ... so... it is doomed; if you forget about serialization and just do `new copyMechanics()`: does it do the same thing?

Comment: I *think* that means you found the underlying issue?